# 256 (maximally) distinct markers in Google Fusion Table Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I have **400k** points in the following format:

```
latitude  longitude  label
```

where label is a number between (0, 256). I want to show them on a map with **distinct** colors/markers.

I am mapping the points now using the *label* column as type text and the results are [here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1IlILOvl4qhiHnuQ9U8r7DBTQ_jXRhLPjYNwBIqV7).

**The problem:**
It seems that some labels have the same marker, specially the ones that are shown red in the map despite having different labels. I know that this column should have the name of the marker.

The question:
Is there any way I can **automatically** map the *label* column into 256 distinct markers?

Comment: Instead of labels I used a list of markers https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=308519#map:id=3 and I set the styles to use that column. Now I can see 256 different markers (e.g. animals, signs, etc.) but it would be great if I could have 256 different markers where the text or color could be different rather than having various signs.